# Store external token using msal-angular

Tags: android, angular, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have an angular web applicaton using Azure AD B2C for access control.

I have a different Android application that use the same authentication system.

Currently, the Android App can open the original web application, but it requires the user to log in again.

The user has to log into the web app separately, in spite of having already logged in via the Android app.

I feel I ought to be able to pass the token acquired by the Android App to the web app, possibly storing it in local storage for @azure/msal-angular to use.

This ought ought to be a trivial issue, but I can't see a straightforward solution.

Comment: When logging in the Android app, do you use system native browser, like Chrome? The case is that you cannot share tokens between applications. Azure AD B2C creates session for the user and basing on that you can get new token for the second application. However in this case you have to use system browser to make sure that Azure AD B2C can drop session cookie that will be used when user will try to log in from another application (also using system browser).